# Find Average Mark For Each User - Mysql

Tags: mysql, average

First table :

`UserId   UserName
  1        User1
  2        User2
  3        User3
  4        User4`

Second Table

`Userid Mark Aptitude English Technical Status 
   1     40     1        0       0         S
   1     30     0        1       0         F
   2     60     0        0       1         S
   2     75     0        1       0         F
   2     25     0        1       0         F
   3     45     1        0       0         F
   3     45     1        0       0         D
   3     50     0        0       1         F
   3     50     0        0       1         F`

I have this two table. I need a query to get the each user average mark in English, Aptitude and Technical. The average should be calculated only for status F. The result should be like this

`UserId  AptitudeAverage  EnglishAverage  TechnicalAverage
    1         0                30            0
    2         0                50            0 
    3         45                0            50
    4          0                0             0`

Comment: What is the basis for calculation of average.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Just normal average by avg method

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and **what has been done so far to solve it**.

Comment: Then for userid 1 how english is 45

Comment: @Luizgrs I can only get the average of any one of the test like Aptitude in a single query. I need all the three tests [Aptitude, English, Technical] in a same query.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai The thrid table values are not correct. But it has to be in that format.

Comment: Can you plz tell what should be the correct value so it will be more easier for us to solve

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I have changed the table. Please take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT userID, IFNULL(AVG(case when Aptitude = 1 then Mark * Aptitude end), 0) AS AptitudeAverage,
               IFNULL(AVG(case when English = 1 then Mark * English end), 0) AS EnglishAverage,
               IFNULL(AVG(case when Technical = 1 then Mark * Technical end), 0) AS TechnicalAverage
FROM YOUR_TAB
WHERE Status = 'F'
GROUP BY userID;
```

This might help you.

Here is the fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e449f/21

Comment: Thanks a lot Ankit. It worked. But If I had a user4 who doesn't have entry in second table, then how to calculate his average too. See the tables. I have updated.